# Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 listener process stopped

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

When I am checking my servers I see that there is an error about listener process stopped. 
I logged in and checked the status of listenere. please see the below status;

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener    
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    TNS-00511: No listener
      Solaris Error: 146: Connection refused
        Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC0)))
          TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
            TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
              TNS-00511: No listener
                Solaris Error: 2: No such file or directory>
```

I am thinking of just running the `start` command but my concern is why is this issue arised ?

Answer (score 4):

There is probably not enough logged at the default level to give you any real insight to root cause, so the best thing to do is restart the listener at a higher logging level. Enter

```
LSNRCTL> trace admin
LSNRCTL> save_config
LSNRCTL> start
```

Then if it crashes again, you'll know why. You can also set the variables `trc_directory`, `trc_file` and `trc_level` to customize this behavior.

Also your `HOST=0.0.0.0` looks odd to me... Shouldn't that be the IP address of your host? What do you have in `LISTENER.ORA`?

Comment: thanks for your comments Gaius; I checked the oracle instance on my both server. and see that the problemmatic server has nothing working belongs the oracle user. 

ps -ef returns nothing related with oracle user. in this case it seems oracle instance has stopped.

Comment: would it be enough for me to use >startup commmand or do I need to use something else ?

Comment: You mean to restart Oracle? Yes `startup` in SQL*Plus will do it. If once started you do `show parameter background_dump_dest` and look in that directory there will be an alert log file that should give you a clue as to why it stopped.

Comment: I tried to startup the server but couldn't make it get working. I checked the alarm in bdomp directory and find the error below : 

Tue Apr  5 10:36:24 2011
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
Tue Apr  5 10:36:26 2011
ORA-00202: control file: '/ldap/oracle/oradata/mtv/control01.ctl'
ORA-27086: unable to lock file - already in use
SVR4 Error: 11: Resource temporarily unavailable
Additional information: 8
Additional information: 22464..

I think an invisible process preventing me from starting the server. I will restart the server ( not oracle )and try to start the db instance again. wish me luck :)

Comment: Is that a local disk or is it NFS? There may still be a lock hanging around on the storage device.

Comment: I tried to kill all processes and start oracle again but no luck it didn't started. by the way I am follwing the below commands to make oracle up and running.
---------
check it:
`su - oracle
sqlplus / as sysdba`
If it says Connected to an idle instance, it means that the instance is not
started. Do the following:
`lsnrct start;

emctl start dbconsole;

sqlplus / as sysdba;

startup (in sqlplus session);`

You will get some feedback about the current status of the services and the
results of the commands